# What does construction ^(int&) mean in c#?

Tags: c#

I found this construction with decompiler tool. Looks like it is something connected with multithreading. what does mean `^(int&)` in c#?

upd

It used like variable declaration

`^(int&) @someLock`

Comment: Can you please post the surrounding code as well?

Comment: Look at [`&` Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx) and [`^` Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx).

Comment: To the others here answering or commenting, [please read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is invalid code, unsafe or not.

---

**Assumption:** The person writing the decompiler comes from a C/C++ background and did not know how to construct legal C# code (if at all possible) for a construct found in IL.

If we're following the breadcrumbs of the "operators" involved, this *could* mean this:

`@someLock` is a variable that will hold the value at some place in memory (`&` means it is actually an address, and `^` means we're dereferencing the address).

Basically, it could be "the value at some specific point in memory", crammed into a single variable declaration. Think of it as a variable that is placed specifically at some address. From knowledge (and I may absolutely be wrong here), IL can handle this, but C# cannot.

Answer (score 1):

This is unsafe code. It returns pointer to memory address